# How to input answers to a shell script automatically using a a batch file?

Tags: shell, batch-file, automation

I have a shell script that that has some questions that nee to be answered(Answers are in form of strings). I have to make another batch file that opens the shelll script and answers the questions automatically. the problem i am facing is that when i open the shell script on cmd using my batch file, i get stuck on the shell script. Any ideas on what commands i will need to input the answers automatically?

Comment: Edit the question, post the code that causes a problem

Comment: Without code we are unable to help you ?

Comment: Having ScriptA calling ScriptB. ScriptB ask questions that ScriptA must answered. Are you able to modify ScriptB to accept argument and have ScriptA call ScriptB with the answers as arguments ?

Answer (score 1):

Generically, you need to use either redirection with a temporary file, or a pipe.

I'll assume your controller batch file needs to provide three answers to script.bat.

## Using Redirection

```
@echo off
>answers.txt echo answer1
>>answers.txt echo answer2
>>answers.txt echo answer3
call script.bat <answers.txt
del answers.txt
```

or you can use a single redirection if you use parentheses

```
@echo off
>answers.txt (
  echo answer1
  echo answer2
  echo answer3
)
call script.bat <answers.txt
del answers.txt
```

## Using a Pipe

```
@echo off
(
  echo answer1
  echo answer2
  echo answer3
) | script.bat
```